# Creating new link in excel

Tags: hyperlink, excel-formula

In Excel I am trying to have it automatically generate a new URL link (column D, row 3). Using a base URL link (listed for example purposes below as `http://vxyz/` in column A, row 3) and then adding two additional non-numerical pieces of information (client name & campaign=columns B and C, row 3). What formula would I use to generate this type of information? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
A              B               C            D
Base URL       client name     Campaign     New URL

http://vxyz/   jsmith          e1v1         ?
```

Comment: [`HYPERLINK` function](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/HYPERLINK-function-fb589fd2-3bc8-4f56-bcac-6b8a79d64230)

Answer (score 1):

the formula is:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(A3, B3, C3))
```

Comment: @cgallant: If this answer solved the problem (which it looks like it should), mark it Accepted with the gray checkmark below the vote buttons.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted. Not sure what more explanation you can give than "HYPERLINK function is for this exact purpose", but there it is.)

Answer (score 0):

**Excel 2013**

[ENCODEURL](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/encodeurl-function-HA102780999.aspx) is needed to encode special charactes, but it's only available in Excel 2013.

`=CONCATENATE(A2,"/",ENCODEURL(B2),"/",ENCODEURL(C2))`